# Last-child selector only works when no div follows

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm working on a project which involves messages that appear at the top. However, last-child doesn't seem to work when trying to select the last error message shown. You can see this here: http://jsfiddle.net/XNVCz/

However, when I take away the small bit of code at the end of the HTML;

```
<div class="container"></div>
```

Then last-child works again even though that div is not of the same class. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: where is the js code in jsfiddle

Comment: I don't think there should be js in that fiddle at all.

Comment: The :last-child CSS pseudo-class represents any element that is the last child element of its parent, and when you have `<div class="container"></div>` as the last child div, the rule doesn't hold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put your `<div class="message">` in a parent divider in order to scope them with ':last-child'.

[jsfiddle.net/XNVCz/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/XNVCz/1/)

```
<div>
    <div class="messager err">
        <div> <strong>Error:</strong> You did not enter the verification code properly.
            <a class="closemessage"><span aria-hidden="true" class="icon-x"></span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="messager err">
        <div> <strong>Error:</strong> You did not enter the verification code properly.
            <a class="closemessage"><span aria-hidden="true" class="icon-x"></span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `:last-child` selector is unaware of classes.

It selects the element if it's *"the last child element of its parent element"* ( [reference](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-lastchild) ) regardless of classes, id-s etc.

Comment: So then how would I select the last message class div?

Comment: @DavidLougheed AFAIK you can't achieve that with pure CSS. You'll need JS for that

Comment: or if you know that you'll have just **one** `<div>` after your error elements than you can use `:nth-last-child` - http://jsfiddle.net/XNVCz/3/

Answer (score 1):

`:last-child` as the name implies *selects* the *last child* of its parent (if it also matches the previous, element-name, part of the selector.

It does not, however, acknowledge class-names; therefore your selector `.messager:last-child` is looking to match *only* the `:last-child` of the parent.

And, clearly, when you insert another element as the last-child of the common parent, the other element is no longer the last-child of that parent. And, as yet, there is no `:last-of-class` selector, sadly.

Comment: Sorry, i am the one who did not understand. I was saying same has you, with a bad french-to-english translation.

Comment: +1 for : " And, as yet, there is no :last-of-class selector, sadly."